# How is a prime a product of primes? [singleton products]

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

In my discrete math my textbook is now covering prime factorization. It states that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic states:

> Every positive integer other than 1 can be expressed uniquely as a product of prime numbers where the prime factors are written in non-decreasing order.

My confusion is how can you write a prime number as a factor of prime numbers? Take  7 for instance. You cannot write 7 as the product of prime numbers, right? Since 1 is not a prime number, you cannot express 7 as 7 * 1.

Is my misunderstanding something with the definition of "product"? Can only one number be considered a product?

Example: 7 can be written as the product of 7. (This doesn't sound right to me)

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: $10=5\times 2$. $7=7$. Just one factor is still a factor. Your example is correct. Yes, a product can have just one term.

Comment: $\large \color{#c00}{n=1}\,\Rightarrow\, p_1 =\! \displaystyle \prod_{\Large k\ =\ 1}^{\Large\color{#c00} n} p_k\ \ \ $

Comment: linguistically it seems strange to say a product, a sum, a sequence, etc with only one term.  But logistically there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can define products with any number of factors in $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. The only product with $0$ factors is, by definition, $1$. This kind of makes sense, since $1$ is the neutral element for multiplication. Moreover, this definition is handy whenever you define a product of $n$ factors but $n$ could be $0$. And then of course the product of one factor is the factor itself. From $2$ on, we know how it works. Hence it is just a matter of defining what a product is.

Comment: Indeed! It’s interesting to ask why the original statement *excluded* $1$, since there is only one way not to choose any prime numbers to multiply.

Answer (score 3):

Yes a single prime is considered a product with just one factor in it.

We have anti intuitive  cases like this in mathematics.

For example  we define $n^0 =1$ or $0!=1$

Comment: and $n^1=n{{}}$.

Comment: Good point for clarity